# How can you do a factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset

I have a ZTE grand x max+. It seem like I can never get out of ftm mode. On this phone. So can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> You can find the option to factory reset most Android Devices in the
>   settings menu. Simply navigate to your device's settings, scroll down
>   until you see '*Backup and Reset*', and then hit '*Factory Data
>   Reset*'. **Please remember that this will wipe everything on your
>   device (unless given the option when you click it to wipe the user's
>   data or not).**
>
> Good luck fixing your problem!

**EDIT:** My mistake. I was too quick to answer. After researching FTM mode, I have found that you should be able to factory reset your phone from the Recovery Menu as you don't have access to Android itself. To get to the recovery menu, take the following steps:

1. Turn off your device.
2. Press and hold both the Volume Up button and Power button at the same time.
3. Let go once a menu appears. There should be an option visible saying Factory Reset.
4. Navigate to the Factory Reset button with the Volume Keys, and use the Power Key to select this.
5. Confirm Factory Reset, and the process will begin.
6. Your phone is now Factory Reset! Click the Power Button to 'Reboot Device Now'.

Comment: I cant do that cause it is stuck on ftm mode

Comment: I have modified my answer. Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: All it did was make the phone blank and won't turn on for a while.

Comment: And i am still stuck on ftm mode

Comment: This thread may help you. http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/stuck-ftm-mode-t2094720

Comment: It did not work.